# "\" and \"" added when adding documents from Json to mongo DB

Tags: scala, play-reactivemongo

my json looks like this.

```
[
  {"name": "AABC Register Ltd (Architects accredited in building conservation), with effect from the 2016 to 2017 tax year"},
  {"name": "Academic and Research Surgery Society of"},
  {"name": "Academic Gaming and Simulation in Education and Training Society for"},
  {"name": "Academic Primary Care Society for"}
]
```

and the code I use to parse this and add it to mongoDB is this

```
val sourceOrganisations: JsValue = Json.parse(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/json/ApprovedOrganisations.json"))

val organisations: Seq[String] = (sourceOrganisations.as[JsArray] \\ "name").map(jsval => jsval.toString())

println(organisations)

organisations.foreach(organisation => this.insert(Organisation(organisation)))
```

when querying mongo i get

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c3dcf309770222486f50b4a"), "name" : "\"Accounting Association American\"" }
```

but i want this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c3dcf309770222486f50b4a"), "name" : "Accounting Association American" }
```

I have tried looking at why there might be extra quotes but can't find the reason

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are doing a toString on JsValue.

When you do a toString on a JsValue which is a JsString you get a String which has the value `"value_inside_JsString"`

```
val jsValue: JsValue = JsString("a")
val extraQuotedString = "[[" + jsValue.toString() + "]]"
// extraQuotedString: String = [["a"]]
```

The correct way is to first cast it to JsString and the getting its value by `.value`.

```
val correctString = "[[" + jsValue.as[JsString].value + "]]"
// correctString: String = [[a]]
```

So,

```
val json = Json.parse(jsonString)

val organizationsAsJsValues = json match {
  case jsArray: JsArray => jsArray \\ "name"
  case _ => Seq.empty[JsValue]
}

val organizationAsNames = organizationsAsJsValues.flatMap({
  case jsString: JsString => Some(jsString.value)
  case _ => None
})

val organizations = organizationAsNames.map(name => Organization(name))
```

Comment: You can do `as[String]` directly. But even better to make a case class for the whole structure and do `val myData = Json.parse(jsonString).as[MyStructure]`.

Comment: @Thilo yes, but that comes after basic understanding of what is actually going on because use of "macro" generated `Reader` and `Writer` hides the whole logical flow.

Comment: True, those are a bit gnarly.

Answer (score 0):

```
val organisations: Seq[String] = (sourceOrganisations.as[JsArray] \\ "name").map(jsval => jsval.toString().replaceAll("\"",""))
```

added 
replaceAll("\"","") to line to fix it. have no clue why it added the qoutes though

Comment: It added the quotes, because you asked it to. `jsval.toString` produces a String with the JSON encoding of `jsval`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsval => jsval.toString()
```

This will give you the JSON representation of `jsval`. If that was a JsString, it will be the double quoted (and potentially escaped) text content.

You probably want to parse the JSON into a case class (`sourceOrganisation = Json.parse(something).as[TheCaseClass]`). That way, you can also avoid doing the manual parsing with `jsArray \\ "name"`

Or at least the final extract the String from the final `jsval` (if you know that it's a JsString, you could do `jsval.as[String]`).